# Creating wordpress admin page panel [Theme Option]

Tags: plugins, php, css

I am learning how to create Wordpress theme options everything works perfectly but when I click save it returns setting successfully saved but when I check the page nothing is changed, can someone please check my code and tell me what is wrong with my code or what is missing ? ,

Here is code:

PHP & HTML CODE:

```
    //1.Defining variables to handle theme name and its shortcut
    $themename = "Bdts options";
    $shortname = "BD";

    //Automatically generate a list of WordPress categories, 
    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
    $wp_cats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
           $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
    }
    array_unshift($wp_cats, "Choose a category");


    //2. Creating  list of options for the theme.
    $options = array (

      //Array to creat panel title
    array( 
        "name" => $themename." Options",
        "type" => "title"),


    array( "name" => "General",
        "type" => "section"),
    array( "type" => "open"),

    array( "name" => "Colour Scheme",
        "desc" => "Select the colour scheme for the theme",
        "id" => $shortname."_color_scheme",
        "type" => "select",
        "options" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
        "std" => "blue"),

    array( "name" => "Logo URL",
        "desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
        "id" => $shortname."_logo",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => ""),


    array( "name" => "Custom CSS",
        "desc" => "Want to add any custom CSS code? Put in here, and the rest is taken care of. This overrides any other stylesheets. eg: a.button{color:green}",
        "id" => $shortname."_custom_css",
        "type" => "textarea",
        "std" => ""),        

    array( "type" => "close"),
    array( "name" => "Homepage",
        "type" => "section"),
    array( "type" => "open"),

    array( "name" => "Homepage header image",
        "desc" => "Enter the link to an image used for the homepage header.",
        "id" => $shortname."_header_img",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => ""),

    array( "name" => "Homepage featured category",
        "desc" => "Choose a category from which featured posts are drawn",
        "id" => $shortname."_feat_cat",
        "type" => "select",
        "options" => $wp_cats,
        "std" => "Choose a category"),


    array( "type" => "close"),
    array( "name" => "Footer",
        "type" => "section"),
    array( "type" => "open"),

    array( "name" => "Footer copyright text",
        "desc" => "Enter text used in the right side of the footer. It can be HTML",
        "id" => $shortname."_footer_text",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => ""),

    array( "name" => "Google Analytics Code",
        "desc" => "You can paste your Google Analytics or other tracking code in this box. This will be automatically added to the footer.",
        "id" => $shortname."_ga_code",
        "type" => "textarea",
        "std" => ""),    

    array( "name" => "Custom Favicon",
        "desc" => "A favicon is a 16x16 pixel icon that represents your site; paste the URL to a .ico image that you want to use as the image",
        "id" => $shortname."_favicon",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => get_bloginfo('url') ."/favicon.ico"),   

    array( "name" => "Feedburner URL",
        "desc" => "Feedburner is a Google service that takes care of your RSS feed. Paste your Feedburner URL here to let readers see it in your website",
        "id" => $shortname."_feedburner",
        "type" => "text",
        "std" => get_bloginfo('rss2_url')),


    array( "type" => "close")

    );

    //This function is meant for updating options, as well as adding a menu page


    function mytheme_add_admin() {

    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($options as $value) {
            update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }

    foreach ($options as $value) {
        if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }

        header("Location: admin.php?page=admin-options.php&saved=true");
    die;

    } 
    else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

        foreach ($options as $value) {
            delete_option( $value['id'] ); }

        header("Location: admin.php?page=admin-options.php&reset=true");
    die;

    }
    }

    add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
    }


    function mytheme_add_init() {
    $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/functions.css", false, "1.0", "all");
    wp_enqueue_script("script", $file_dir."/script.js", false, "1.0");
    }



    function mytheme_admin() {

    global $themename, $shortname, $options;
    $i=0;

    if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';

    ?>
    <div class="wrap rm_wrap">
    <h2><?php echo $themename; ?> Settings</h2>

    <div class="rm_opts">
    <form method="post">

    <?php foreach ($options as $value) {
    switch ( $value['type'] ) {

    case "open":
    ?>

    <?php break;

    case "close":
    ?>

    </div>
    </div>
    <br />


    <?php break;

    case "title":
    ?>
    <p>To easily use the <?php echo $themename;?> theme, you can use the menu below.</p>


    <?php break;

    case 'text':
    ?>

    <div class="rm_input rm_text">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <input name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_option( $value['id'])  ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" />
     <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small><div class="clearfix"></div>

     </div>
    <?php
    break;

    case 'textarea':
    ?>

    <div class="rm_input rm_textarea">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <textarea name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" cols="" rows=""><?php if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_option( $value['id']) ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?></textarea>
     <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small><div class="clearfix"></div>

     </div>

    <?php
    break;

    case 'select':
    ?>

    <div class="rm_input rm_select">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>

    <select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
            <option <?php if (get_option( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php } ?>
    </select>

        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small><div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    break;

    case "checkbox":
    ?>

    <div class="rm_input rm_checkbox">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>

    <?php if(get_option($value['id'])){ $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; }else{ $checked = "";} ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />


        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small><div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
    <?php break;


    case "section":

    $i++;

    ?>


    <div class="rm_section">
    <div class="rm_title"><h3><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/trans.png" class="inactive" alt="""><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3><span class="submit"><input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
    </span><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
    <div class="rm_options">


    <?php break;

    }
    }
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
    </form>
    <form method="post">
    <p class="submit">
    <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
    </p>
    </form>
    <div style="font-size:9px; margin-bottom:10px;">
     </div> 







    <?php
    }

    ?>

    <?php
    add_action('admin_init', 'mytheme_add_init');
    add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');



    ?>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.rm_wrap{
    width:740px;
}
.rm_section{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:0;
    background:#f9f9f9;
}
.rm_opts label{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    float:left; 
}
.rm_input {
    padding:30px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}

.rm_opts{
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}


.rm_opts small{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    color:#999;
}
.rm_opts input[type="text"], .rm_opts select{
    width:280px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px;
    color:#333;
    line-height:1em;
    background:#f3f3f3;
}
.rm_input input:focus, .rm_input textarea:focus{
        background:#fff;
}
.rm_input textarea{
    width:280px;
    height:175px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:4px;
    color:#333;
    line-height:1.5em;
    background:#f3f3f3;
}
.rm_title h3 {
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#232323;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    padding:14px 4px;
}
.rm_title{
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    background:#eee;
    padding:0;
}
.rm_title h3 img.inactive{
    margin:-8px 10px 0 2px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;    
    background:url('http://127.0.0.1:81/Andrzejki/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pointer.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    float:left;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.rm_title h3 img.active{
    margin:-8px 10px 0 2px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;    
    background:url('http://127.0.0.1:81/Andrzejki/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pointer.png') no-repeat  0 -32px;
    float:left;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}       
.rm_title h3:hover img{
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.rm_title span.submit{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:15%;
    padding:14px 0;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
.rm_table th, .rm_table td{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.rm_table th, .rm_table td.feature{
    border-color:#888;
    }
```

Comment: WordPress prevent option page for theme. You need to use customizer to register your options.

Comment: how to do that ?